# value in angular service setting to undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, service

i have 2 components comp A and comp B. when i click on a button in comp A, the value from the button goes to a service via Subject in RxJS. the button click also triggers a routerLink to change to comp B. the contents of comp B is based on the value of the button. Its working alright. WHen i click on the button the contents is displayed in comp B but when i refresh the page the service no longer holds the value that it recieved from comp A and that's why the values in comp B isnt shown. Any idea or workaround for this?

my comp A:

```
onClickChange(event,index:number){
        this.statename=(this.renderedData[index].Name) 
        this.apiService.sendStateName(this.statename)    
        this.router.navigate(['/CompB']);
    }
```

my service:

```
private subject=new BehaviorSubject<string>("DefaultValue")    
    name=this.subject.asObservable()    
    sendStateName(statename:string){    
      this.subject.next(statename)   
      this.name=statename
    }

getData():Observable<State>{    
  return this.httpClient.get<>('http://localhost:8000/'+this.name)  
}
```

Comment: Please show the codes of Comp A, Comp B and the service.

Comment: i have mentioned for comp A and service. compB is just utilizing it

Comment: If you will refresh the webpage, the service data will be lost .You can better store the data to localStorage to persist until you delete it manually

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi thank you working with local storage works.

Comment: @HelloWorld , glad to know that ! Happy learning!